# Cordova build uses wrong res path

Tags: ios, cordova, path

I'm using cordova build to generate an iOS project for my app. In my config.xml I specified the following resources:

```
    <icon height="29" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="40" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="50" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="57" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="res/icons/ios/icon-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="60" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" />
    <splash height="480" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <splash height="960" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1136" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1024" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="2048" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" />
```

(./res and res were also tried)

When I run `cordova buid ios` I get an error for each of these specified files:

```
cp: no such file or directory: /path/to/project/config.xml/res/icons/ios/icon-60.png
```

It looks like config.xml is used as a directory. (The correct path is without config.xml). How can fix this?

Comment: what cordova ios version are you using? There seems to be an similar issue with cordova ios 4.0.0 which got closed in ios 4.0.1 More info in the follwing link - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10172

Comment: Indeed, it's fixed after updating to cordova-ios 4.1 (strange, because I tried that earlier). The images are working now, but now the index.html can't be found :-(

Answer (score 1):

For those in need:

After hours of debugging I figured out that cordova-ios incorrectly implemented the various paths. After fixing this myself I found out this was already done in a newer version in [this commit](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/commit/d9d12638d2fb6e6c39f56011ffdcb213fafbee8d).

Solutions was removing cordova-ios `cordova platform remove ios` and re-adding using `cordova platform add ios@latest`.